# Only one image is showing up on OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, image, png, ext-js

I can only get one of the following DEM_image PNGs to show up on my map.  Its always the first one "DSS.layer.DEM.image0" that shows up, the rest do not render.  I can see in the console that the others are loading, but still arent showing up.  Each PNG is around 10mb.  What is going on here?  Is there a work around to make sure all of these show up?

```
 DSS.layer.DEM_image0 = new ol.layer.Image({
            source:
            new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: '/static/grazescape/public/images/SW_DEM_PNG_1122_v2_0.PNG',
                imageExtent: [ -10168109.314900, 5318375.349200, -10111969.314900, 5386305.349200],
            })
        }),
        DSS.layer.DEM_image1 = new ol.layer.Image({
            source:
            new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: '/static/grazescape/public/images/SW_DEM_PNG_1122_v2_1.PNG',
                imageExtent: [ -10111969.314900, 5318375.349200, -10055829.314900, 5386305.349200],
                imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {}
            })
        }),
        DSS.layer.DEM_image2 = new ol.layer.Image({
            source:
            new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: '/static/grazescape/public/images/SW_DEM_PNG_1122_v2_2.PNG',
                imageExtent: [ -10168109.314900, 5386305.349200, -10111969.314900, 5454235.349200],
                
            })
        }),
        DSS.layer.DEM_image3 = new ol.layer.Image({
            source:
            new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: '/static/grazescape/public/images/SW_DEM_PNG_1122_v2_3.PNG',
                imageExtent: [ -10111969.314900, 5386305.349200, -10055829.314900, 5454235.349200],
                
            })
        })



me.map = DSS.map = new ol.Map({
            maxTilesLoading: 100,
            target: me.down('#ol_map').getEl().dom,
            layers: [
                //DSS.layer.bingAerial,
                //DSS.layer.bingRoad,
                DSS.layer.osm,
                //DSS.layer.DEMGroup,
                
                DSS.layer.DEM_image0,
                DSS.layer.DEM_image1,
                DSS.layer.DEM_image2,
                DSS.layer.DEM_image3,
                DSS.layer.kickapoowatershed,
                DSS.layer.rullandsCouleewshed,
                DSS.layer.tainterwatershed,
                DSS.layer.scenarios,
                DSS.layer.farms_1,
                ],
```

Comment: Unless the image width/height ratio exactly matches that of the extent a canvas will be used to scale it.  A 10mb image is likely to be very close to the browser limit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#maximum_canvas_size

Comment: For sure your `DEM_image1` won't be shown because of empty `imageLoadFunction` function. I tried with three 14MB images and had no problems. If PNG images have no transparency, only the last one is visible.  Have you tried to experiment with `opacity` and `zIndex` options?

Comment: There has been a recent fix in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/13073 so it may be worth trying the latest dev version.